# A block of code skips on the second iteration of the while loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, while-loop

I have this code that asks the user for `x` and `y`:

```cs
do
{
    Console.Write("x = ");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();
    if (str.ToLower().Equals("exit"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program has stopped");
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        while (!int.TryParse(str, out x))
        {
            Console.Write("x = ");
            str = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        while (!int.TryParse(yVal, out y))
        {
            Console.Write("y = ");
            yVal = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide ?");
    f = Console.ReadLine();
    if (f.ToLower().Equals("add"))
    {
        sum = x + y;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", sum);
    }
    else if (f.ToLower().Equals("subtract"))
    {
        difference = x - y;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", difference);
    }
    else if (f.ToLower().Equals("multiply"))
    {
        product = x * y;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", product);
    }
    else if (f.ToLower().Equals("divide"))
    {
        quotient = x / y;
        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", quotient);
    }
}
while (true);
```

- It runs smoothly on the first try but
- On the second it asks for the `x` and skips asking the `y` directly

How can I solve this?

Comment: set `yVal` to a default value at the end of your do-while-loop.

Comment: @SomeBody i'm sorry i am still new to programming. how do I do that?

Comment: `yVal = ""`any where after the `while (!int.TryParse(yVal`. Because your previous input is still in yVal. `while (!int.TryParse( Console.ReadLine(), out y))` that way there is no more caching of user input in a variable.

Comment: You might want to check out [ExtendedConsole](https://peled-zohar.github.io/ExtendedConsole/). It's an open source MIT licensed project designed to make your life easier when writing console applications. Full disclosure - I'm it's author and (at least currently) it's sole maintainer.